# Index page with datatable took about 6-7 seconds before showing search box

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datatable, datatables

I have a simple index page. When I load the page with only 500 records, the search box shows up straight away. But with 12k records, it take some time. Is there a way I can show a LOADING message, and after the search box is loaded, the LOADING message disappear.

This is the Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<BSMV2.Models.StoAppnOrgView>
<h2>LIST OF STONES</h2>
<table id="applicationTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Stone)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Applicant)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Org)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Stone)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Applicant)
            </td>
            <td>
                {@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Org)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { Id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#applicationTable').DataTable();
    });

</script>}
```

Here is the controller

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        return View(await db.StoAppnOrgViewObj.ToListAsync());
    }
```

Here is the Search box.
[image]

Comment: Yes... Yes I can show wait icon ... There are plenty of resources available on internet which can demonstrate this... Btw showing 12k records on one page is really a useful requirement for the user? Why not show paginated result with let say 100 records per page and allow user to navigate thru pages... Any simple search on Google results in 10 K items but Google doesn't show all 10k in one page... As a user you will be looking thru all 10k items if they are displayed in one page?

Comment: I don't know your requirement but do you think that a user reads ALL 12K rows? The bottleneck is in `db.StoAppnOrgViewObj` (I suppose a EF table/view). I suggest you: 1. return the first 50 rows and add a button to load more (take/skip) 2. review the generated SQL and search for (index?) optimization.

Comment: I'm showing the paginated result (10 records per page). I forgot to mention that the pagination also only appear after 6-7 seconds, same with the searchbox.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be loading all 12k data on the UI. Instead use server side paging which will give the user similar experience but performance wise will be faster. The system will not be slower. The data will grow over the time and you will have to shift to server side logic anyways in the future.

You can also use the progress indicator that comes with datatable. All you have to do the followings:

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "../server_side/scripts/test.php"
    } );
```

For the server side logic, you can follow the codes from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-jquery-server-side-datatable-example/).

Comment: I end up using a different approach.